# FAQ: How should we tag questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, tagging

What is the proper way of tagging questions? How should we tag them?

[Return to FAQ index](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tagging is very important. According to the way you tag your question, it will be easier for other users to find it and the site will be better organized and clean.

First of all, remember to provide at least **2 tags** for your question. One that considers the broader topic, and one that narrows it down. You can use [this scheme](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/332/111) to guide you.

For example, if your question is about **Phonology**, then you should tag the question [phonology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) and [theoretical-linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-linguistics) since Phonology belongs to that part of Linguistics.