# Proposed FAQ: Should we set some tags as obligatory?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, faq-proposed

After the creation of [this scheme](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/111), I've been thinking, wouldn't it be better if the Macro-categories (Theoretical, Applied, Descriptive) from Linguistics were obligatory tags?

For example, if someone is asking about Phonology, they should include also what this field belongs to: Theoretical Linguistics.

There is a **problem**, though: If a question is about both Phonology and Phonetics, that means we should include **two** macro-categories, i.e. Theoretical **and** Descriptive?

Opinions? Ideas? Criticism?

I'm a bit unsure about this, but I'd like to know what you think on the matter, because if there was a good way to implement this, then it would greatly help our tagging system and better tags mean better search. If this gains consensus and traction, I'll propose the devs to introduce the mandatory tags for the Main Site. If, after all, this is unfeasible, then we'll abandon the proposal.

Comment: Considering the low interest, I'm tagging this `status-declined` for now. :)