# Are questions about translational tools on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since [translation studies is a part of linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/332/5400), and I guess questions about linguistic tools are on-topic here, I guess questions about translational tools are on-topic as well?

Comment: Generally, on topic. But I haven't come across experts in the filed of translation tools here. You could ask your questions, and see how they go.